# How to dynamically display tabs for routes in Durandal?

Tags: durandal-navigation

This is a two part question. Am very new to durandal and knockout.

Using the HTML Starter Kit example for Durandal 2.0.1.

I add a route for customers/:id with my own vm and view with nav = false

```
 { route: 'customer/:id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/customer/customer', nav: false }
```

Because nav is false, it doesn't get used when buildNavigationModel() is called. So the shell.html doesn't show a tab entry for it. So far so good.

1. When I navigate to c:\temp\index.html#customer/123 I can see the page, but it doesn't get included in the tabs at the top of the page. When I look at shell.html it uses data-bind to get the routes to display in those tabs. So shouldn't it display this new route I just moved to? If I set the routes, nav to true, would that be enough to refresh the shell display? Or am I failing at my first attempt to understand ko?
2. So I have a route for customer/:id. If I go to index#customer/123 I want to see a new tab as of part 1 above. If I navigate to index#customer/234, I want to see a new tab for that as well. The user should then be able to move between the two tabs. Can this work, or is it really only recording the customer/:id route and I will only ever see one tab button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router navigation model won't do what you're looking for. Check out [Durandal 2.0 routing parameterized routes (same route different parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906829/) to see an example how to build your own navigation model instead.